# Excel 2013 - Table connection problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Okay I have a real problem on my hands and have spent several hours trying to figure this out. When I add a new column to and external data table (RP_DASH) the additional columns moves the data around (within the column) when I refresh.

Details:
1. QC_Input - Spreadsheet that has manual data entry (100 rows, 14 columns) that will have a separate tab for reporting on this phase (not important)
2. RP_Dash - Spreadsheet that has the connection with QC_Input (100 rows, 14Col + 6 new) and have added 6 additional columns to the right of the connection for further reporting on this stage.

Lets say I insert 1 additional column to the imported data on the RP_Dash and put 1-5 in the first **5** rows.  When I **Refresh** the imported data information will remain the same (as it should) but my data in my newly inserted column will re-arrange itself and look like 3,4,1,2,5.

I don't understand whats going on?

Comment: What type of External Data is it? Access? SQL? Text file?

Comment: Another Excel 2013 table

Comment: Data / External Data doesn't have an option for Excel. Are you going through Microsoft Query? Power Query? Power Pivot? Other?

Answer (score 0):

Create a column that numbers your rows in the original table and then sort that same row in ascending order for your imported data. If you find it too cumbersome to write in numbers for each row, you can set the numbering in the column to equal the row number, i.e. The cell in the 4th row would have the formula =ROW(A4). 
Hope that works!